# SQL Server Update Loop/Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

```
Index   Columns         Text          New Index
===========================================
1   ISOCountry  TH          1
-------------------------------------------
2   Country        Thailand         1
-------------------------------------------
3   Region         Asia         1
-------------------------------------------
4   Date           12/31/2014       1
-------------------------------------------
5   Holiday        New Years Eve    1
-------------------------------------------
7   ISOCountry     DE           2
-------------------------------------------
8   Country        Germany          2
-------------------------------------------
9   Region         EMEA             2
-------------------------------------------
10  Date           12/31/2014       2
-------------------------------------------
11  Holiday        New Years Eve    2
-------------------------------------------
13  ISOCountry  DK          3
-------------------------------------------
14  Country         Denmark         3
-------------------------------------------
15  Region          EMEA            3
-------------------------------------------
16  Date            12/31/2014  3
-------------------------------------------
17  Holiday         New Years Eve   3
-------------------------------------------
```

I have a column as above. I need a loop/cursor in SQL Server such that everytime the Column "Column" changes to ISOCountry, the New Index column has to be incremented by 1. **Which means that for Rows 1 through 5 the New Index column has a value 1, for rows 7 through 11 the New Index value has to be 2 and so on**. The point where the Columns changes to ISO Country the New Index Value has to change to 2 likewise for the rest of the columns. I will have about 10000 rows in all

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why on earth would you store data that way? That is an extremely opoor table design.

Comment: We are getting data from a file in this format... I will use this to convert the table to Transpose the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set the newIndex based on the number of ISOCountry records prior to the current record:

```
UPDATE A
SET newIndex = B.newIndex
FROM [myTable] A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) [newIndex]
    FROM [myTable] X
    WHERE   X.[Index] <= A.[Index]
        AND X.[Columns] = 'ISOCountry'
) B
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a loop?  Just set the `newindex` value to the count of `isocountry` records with a lower id.  You can do this with a correlated subquery (as well as with other methods):

```
update table t
    set newindex = (select count(*)
                    from table t2
                    where t2.columns = 'IsoCountry' and
                          t2."index" <= t."index"
                   );
```